# C++ Multithread program on linux memory issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, debian

I'm developing a software that requires creation and deletion of a large number of threads.

When I create a thread the memory increases and when delete them (this is confirmed by using the command `ps -mo THREAD -p <pid>`), the memory related to the program/software does not decrease (top command). As a result I run out of memory.

I have used Valgrind to check for memory error/leak and I can't find any.  This is on a debian box. Please let me know what the issue could be.

Comment: How you understand, that you run out of memory? Using `free -m` or the program crashes, because of out-of-memory?

Comment: the program crashes and before that could identify through top command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you deleting the threads?
The notes here http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html talk about needing to call join in some cases to free up resources.

Comment: calling join didnt do the trick but calling pthread_detach() worked. Thanks

Comment: If you are creating and deleting large numbers of threads continuously you might look into using a thread pool instead... I have to idea if that's applicable to your application though

Comment: True. Currently I'm using thread pool. but I have a large number of small pools who's size keep changing. Investigating if this causes performance issue,if yes then would think of changing the design.

Answer (score 0):

You do not run out of memory.

The "free memory" you see in top command is actually not the memory that is available when required. Linux kernel uses as much as possible/useable of the free memory for its page cache. When a process requires memory, the kernel can throw away that page cache and provide that memory to a process.

In other words: linux uses the free memory, instead of just leaving it idling around...

Use `free -m`: In the row labeled "-/+ buffers/cache:" you will see the real amount of memory available for processes.